# Knockoutjs - Setting the context of functions

Tags: knockout.js, binding, this

I'm doing a tutorial where the author is explaining various ways he setting the context of functions. One way is declaring a variable `self = this` and another is passing the object as the second argument  in the function, i.e.: `ko.computed(function)(){...}, my.vm)`.  I understand those two concepts, however, I am confused as to why he is passing `this` as the second argument in the following function:

```
       $(function (){
           var photoPath = "/images/";

           my.Product = function () {
                this.id = ko.observable();
                this.salePrice = ko.observable();
                this.photo = ko.observable();
                this.shortDescription = ko.observable();
                this.photoUrl = ko.computed(function () {
                    return photoPath + this.photo();
                }, this);
            };
       });
```

Would anyone here please explain this to me?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of a `computed()` observable is the "owner" of the observable. That is, when the value is computed, it is what will be used as `this` in the accessor functions.

e.g,

```
var a = { foo: 1 };
var b = { foo: 2 };
ko.computed(function () { return this.foo; }, a); // 1
ko.computed(function () { return this.foo; }, b); // 2
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff Mercado.  I understand the owner is being set.  But isn't the owner already being set in the `my.Product` model object?  Why would the `this` in the `ko.computed` function be different from the model object?